# Isn't the result true for any $A\subset X?$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

There's a problem in my text which reads as:

Let $f: (X, d)\to(Y, d)$ be continuous. Let $A\subset X$ be open. Show that the restriction $f|_A$ of $f$ to $A$ is a continuous function from the metric space $(A, d)$ to $(Y, d)$. (Here the metric on A is the induced metric.)

> My question is whether mentioning $A$ to be open necessary? Isn't the result true for any $A\subset X?$

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is (let $A$ denote any subset of $X$): We know that $S\subseteq A$ is open in $A$ if and only if $S=A\cap U$ for some $U$ open in $X$. Let $B$ be an open subset of $Y$ and $U=f^{-1}(B), S=(f|_A)^{-1}(B)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $U$ is open in $X$, hence $S=A\cap U$ is open in $A$ and so $f|_A$ is continuous. Note also that this proof works for any topological space, not just metric spaces.